# Triple Deep Population - Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose for my nodejs app, i want to populate to depth of 3

A service has a car and a car has a model and a model has a brand

```
Service.find({removed:false,client:req.client_id})
      .populate({path:'car',model:"ClientCar",populate:{path:"model",model:"Model"}})
      .exec(function(err,services)
      {})
```

when adding brand in the second populate it fails

```
Service.find({removed:false,client:req.client_id})
      .populate({path:'car',model:"ClientCar",populate:{path:"model",model:"Model",populate{path:"brand",model:"Brand"}})
      .exec(function(err,services)
      {})
```

Answer (score 2):

try this instead:

```
Service.find({removed:false,
client:req.client_id})
  .populate({
       path:'car',
       model:"ClientCar",
       populate:[{
           path:"model",
           model:"Model"
      },
      {
           path: "model.brand",
           model:"Brand"
      }]
  )
  .exec(function(err,services)
  {});
```

to be clear, i mean try this because it's neater. I'm fairly certain the only thing preventing your code from working properly is the missing : after the third populate

```
Service.find({removed:false,client:req.client_id})
  .populate({path:'car',model:"ClientCar",populate:{path:"model",model:"Model",
populate{path:"brand", //here, should be populate: {}, not populate{}
model:"Brand"}})
  .exec(function(err,services)
  {})
```

note: you shouldn't leave lines of code that long, they're hard to read through